# Keras. ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I use jupyter notebook with anaconda. I use kerast firstly, and i can't do tutorial. About this issues are two themes in stackoverflow, but solve not found.

My code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

X_train_shape = X_train.reshape(len(X_train), 1)
Y_train_shape = Y_train.reshape(len(Y_train), 1)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32)
```

And I have error, it's some random and sometimes one or two epoch competed:

> Epoch 1/5  4352/17500 [======>.......................]
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         2 # of 32 samples
>         3 #sleep(0.1)
>   ----> 4 model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32)
>         5 #sleep(0.1)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\models.pyc in fit(self,
>   x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, validation_split,
>   validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, **kwargs)
>       395                               shuffle=shuffle,
>       396                               class_weight=class_weight,
>   --> 397                               sample_weight=sample_weight)
>       398 
>       399     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.pyc in
>   fit(self, x, y, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks,
>   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight,
>   sample_weight)    1009                               verbose=verbose,
>   callbacks=callbacks,    1010
>   val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
>   -> 1011                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics)    1012     1013     def
>   evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.pyc in
>   _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, nb_epoch, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics)
>       753                     batch_logs[l] = o
>       754 
>   --> 755                 callbacks.on_batch_end(batch_index, batch_logs)
>       756 
>       757                 epoch_logs = {}
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.pyc in
>   on_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
>        58         t_before_callbacks = time.time()
>        59         for callback in self.callbacks:
>   ---> 60             callback.on_batch_end(batch, logs)
>        61         self._delta_ts_batch_end.append(time.time() - t_before_callbacks)
>        62         delta_t_median = np.median(self._delta_ts_batch_end)
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\callbacks.pyc in
>   on_batch_end(self, batch, logs)
>       187         # will be handled by on_epoch_end
>       188         if self.verbose and self.seen < self.params['nb_sample']:
>   --> 189             self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values)
>       190 
>       191     def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.pyc
>   in update(self, current, values)
>       110                 info += ((prev_total_width - self.total_width) * " ")
>       111 
>   --> 112             sys.stdout.write(info)
>       113             sys.stdout.flush()
>       114
>
> C:\Anaconda3\envs\py27\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.pyc in
>   write(self, string)
>       315 
>       316             is_child = (not self._is_master_process())
>   --> 317             self._buffer.write(string)
>       318             if is_child:
>       319                 # newlines imply flush in subprocesses
>
> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Does the problem go away if you change your verbose level in model.fit() to verbose=0? See github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2110

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for posting it.

Comment: @Amw5G Could you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your verbose level in 
`model.fit()`
to 
    `verbose=0.`
See [github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2110](http://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2110)

It's not a straight-on "fix", but it should help alleviate a race condition associated with updating of the iPython console.